# Using speedglm with all variables and interactions in R

Tags: regression, machine-learning, generalized-linear-model

```
speedglm(y~.,data=df,family=binomial('logit'))
```

won't work

also trying:

`speedglm(y~(.)^7,data=df,family=binomial('logit'))` for all interaction values, does not work.

```
f<-as.formula("y~(x1+x2+x3)^3")

fit1 = speedglm(f, data=lt, family=binomial('logit'))
```

this works but I want more automatic approach using all variables.

in regular lm,glm i have no problem using this:

```
glm(y~(.)^7,data=df,family=binomial('logit'))
```

Comment: How do they "not work"? What goes wrong?  And you do *not* want something more automatic, automatic variable selection methods are very problematic. And including all possible interactions (up to order 7!) also seems problematic.